# Getting master branch code changes in to local branch in Git?

Tags: git, github

Let say In my repo, Master branch name is FINNI.
And I created sub branch to it and named it as MA_BUG.For the first time i cloned the code using

```
git clone ssh:url
```

and did changes to my MA_BUG branch and committed code to MA_BUG and merged to FINNI.
Some other colleagues also committed to FINNI branch.
Now i want to get fresh (updated) code in FINNI to my MA_BUG.
Can you please give me command.
I have tried

```
git fetch origin FINNI
```

but not getting i'm new to GIT.

Comment: You got the changes to FINNI and you want to merge it with MA_BUG ? or you want to bring what your friends have commited to FINNI?

Answer (score 1):

- `git checkout FINNI`
- `git pull`
- `git checkout MA_BUG`
- `git merge FINNI`

Comment: Scenario like,One bug has been assigned so for the first time i created sub branch MA_BUG of FINNI.I did cloned my clone ,did changes and commited code to MA_BUG.After this proper approval i merged MA_BUG with FINNI.After 10 days one more bug has been assigned.So for this i'm asking without cloning one more time as i have already had MA_BUG branch ,i want all chages in FINNI to come  to MA_BUG so dat i can commit code again to MA_BUG.For this above commands work?

Answer (score 0):

First revert merge in FINNI branch, then update FINNI brach with `git pull origin master'. Then checkout to MA_BUG brach and rebase to FINNI branch. your MA_BUG branch will be updated with FINNI branch. Here is more details about rebase: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase

Comment: why are you asking to revert merge in FINNI.I did not get you

Comment: Otherwise there can be merge conflict with new commit which is done by other colleagues. It good to solve these conflict during rebase in MA_BUG branch. And if you don't, may you have to first forward you FINNI branch with conflict. Which will be mess, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

To get all of the new commits from the remote to the local FINNI run the following:

```
git checkout FINNI
git pull
```

Now all of the new commits are on FINNI branch. You have to merge FINNI into MA_BUG as following :

```
git checkout MA_BUG
git merge FINNI
```

Comment: FINNI is remote master branch not local ,my sub branch is MA_BUG.So i need to get all newly committed code in FINNI to my local MA_BUG